# Module::Build test looks in different directories on different systems

Tags: perl, testing, mojolicious

I'm trying to install a Perl Mojolicious project from a development system onto a staging system.  On the staging system (Centos), the tests are looking in the wrong place for the config file. That is, eg,

```
./Build test --test-files t/001_basic.t
```

errors out with

> t/001_basic.t .. 1/? Configuration file "/home/randall/git/Project/blib/project.json" missing, maybe you need to create it?

On the development system (Ubuntu), the same `Build test` command is reading the config file out of the parent directory (ie, /home/randall/git/Project/project.json) which is what I want.

I've already ruled out the working directory as a possible culprit, and reran `perl Build.PL`, regenerating the Build script.

What am I missing that would cause *only* the staging system to be looking in the blib directory?

**Edit**: Added that dev is Ubuntu and staging is Centos, though I don't expect that to be a factor

Comment: Is it Build.PL that does something special when it's in a git dir? That might be the difference.

Comment: Not that I know of; regardless, on both systems it's in a git directory.  I think this has more to do with the way Mojolicious is finding the config file (using `Mojolicious::Plugin::JSONConfig`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't make assumptions about the current work directory you're given.

```
use Cwd            qw( abs_path );
use File::Basename qw( dirname );

use constant PROJ_DIR => dirname(abs_path(__FILE__)) . '/..';

my $config_qfn = PROJ_DIR.'/project.json';
```

Comment: True.  However, the config file is being loaded through `Mojolicious::Plugin::JSONConfig` which complicates matters in this case; it's supposed to be defaulting to looking " in the application home directory".  I may be coming at this from the wrong angle, though the blib subdir seems to point to Module::Build being involved, and the Mojo app otherwise seemed to find the config file without a problem.  I'll troubleshoot further.

Comment: `blib` is the staging dir. The `make` step places the files to install in `blib` (by copying and creating them), and the `install` step copies from them from `blib` into their final location. `blib` is technically the "application's home directory" when testing.

Comment: To clarify - even after `install`, doesn't a `test` always go against the files in `blib`?

Comment: Yes. `install` has no effect on the staging environnent, so you can pretend it never happened and still run the tests.